# Version Error in IPod

Tags: iphone

I create  an IPhone application in XCode, and i build and run it Simulator. It executed successfully.

Then i connect my device, and then i clicked the Build and Run,  the following error message displayed.

I inserted the provisional also.

How to solve the following error?

The Info.plist for my application  specifies a minimum OS version of 4.1, which is too high to be installed on my iPod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install iOS 4.1 on your iPod, or change your minimum OS setting.

The setting can be changed by going to Project > Edit Project Settings, then finding the value for "iOS Deployment Target".

Set that to match your iPod's current OS.